# Is there any SDK provided by Microsoft for network application development?

Tags: winapi, networking, network-programming

I am writing a Network program, and I am using NP_ENUM_NETWORK in my win32 application.

When I search in my system I am not able to locate this enum. Can I know in which header file, I will get this enum?

Is there any SDK provided by Microsoft for network application development where I can get this enum?

Answer (score 1):

It [seems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms697388(VS.85).aspx) that your desired functionality, headers and examples are part of any [Vista and above SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=ff6467e6-5bba-4bf5-b562-9199be864d29&displaylang=en).

Comment: And note, the naming of the SDK tells you what new things it supports. Older OS' continue to be supported (assuming you define the right version macros before including headers).